# Converting a python program which uses local files to .exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, py2exe

I am trying to convert my python code to an exe file
I have these 4 files [image]

Using google I found a way by using `pyinstaller main.py` but that is only for a single file but in my code, I am using a local file which later on I have to add in the folder where my .exe file is but is there any way I can combine them and share it for people to use it

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to build your .exe with `pyinstaller main.py -F --add-data "ch.jpg;." ...`.
You can specify `--add-data` multiple times, so for each file you want to include.

Then internally you can access your file like this:

```py
import os
from sys import _MEIPASS

open(os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, "ch.jpg"), "r")
```

Basically `_MEIPASS` is a directory where this included files will be created when starting you application.

The syntax for `--add-data` is like that: `file_name;the_real_directory`.

So you can access the file by the name `file_name`, `the_real_directory` describes where the file actually is when building your .exe.
But it's more complex then that, see the docs for more.

EDIT: Also a .spec file is generated when you first build. You can look in there and edit `Analysis(datas=[])` to add all your files.